# Netlogo Expected literal - A different one

Tags: list, netlogo, literals

```
let country-list csv:from-file "countries20.csv"
```

A CSV file with 20 country names in a single row is stored in a Netlogo list.

I need to extract one random element from this list into the variable base-country, so:

```
set base-country one-of country-list
```

This is where I get the infamous `Expected a literal value` error. As I looked at previous posts on this as well as the CSV and List section of Netlogo resources, I already know I should use probably the "list" primitive, and so I did try it:

```
let country-list (list csv:from-file "countries20.csv")
```

but I get the same `Expected a literal value` error at the same line:

```
set base-country one-of country-list
```

Comment: I couldnt reproduce the error, though it isn't working properly, but with one more `one-of` it would work. My minimal working example: ```extensions[csv]

to setup
  let country-list csv:from-file "countries20.csv"
  show country-list
  let base-country one-of country-list
  show base-country
; returns ["germany" " france"]
end```

My csv: "germany, france"

I guess, there must be something wrong about the csv.

Comment: Thank you Lena. I managed to have that error disappear by changing some code that was apparently completely unrelated - and coming after the error - by editing it and placing it beforehand. To this day, I don't know what was wrong. I think that this Expected Literal is an error that Netlogo flags for lots of undiscernable reasons.